# How to makefile parse

Tags: makefile

At the make manual said:

> During the first phase it reads all the makefiles, included makefiles,
>   etc. and internalizes all the variables and their values, implicit and
>   explicit rules, and constructs a dependency graph of all the targets
>   and their prerequisites.

I don't understand how the dependency graph constructed? Consider the following makefile:

```
%.o: %.z
    echo This is overriden implicit rule
default: foo.o

clean:
    rm -f fmake test_second
%.o: %.c
    echo This is customized implicit rule
```

After `make` command

```
echo This is customized implicit rule
This is customized implicit rule
```

is displayed, but I'm expexted that

```
echo This is overriden implicit rule
This is overriden implicit rule
```

will be, because in make rule only overrides if both the target and the prerequisite patterns match. In this case I think that `%.o: %.z` implicit rules matched to pattern already.

Comment: Let me guess: `foo.c` exists, but `foo.z` does not. Am I right?

Comment: @Beta foo.z is exists

Comment: There's no way we can tell you what's going on based on this description.  It all depends on what files exist etc.  The simplest thing for you to do is run make with the `-d` option and make will print out exactly what steps its following.  If indeed there is a `foo.z` file here then the behavior you're seeing should not happen given the makefile here.  So, something in your actual setup is not as you've described it here.

Answer (score 5):

I've been doing a lot of work with Makefiles in a very, very large codebase for the last year or so. I am heartily sick of make(1s)!

The answer, in general, is "last declaration wins". You also have to contend
with the default make suffix rules (on Solaris these are found in /usr/share/lib/make/make.rules).

So if you want your overridden implicit rule to stand, place it last in the
Makefile hierarchy. If you want to flush the suffixes list, you can do either
or both of

## 1 add a    .SUFFIXES:

line to your Makefile,

## 2 call make with   -r

in MAKEFLAGS (env var) or on the make invocation command line.

[Also, you can prepend "@" to the start of your command to just see the output
of it, rather than the

echo [output goes here]

as well as the actual

[output goes here]

You could also gather insight by using one of the debugging options that
make(1s) allows. On Solaris, that's -d, -dd, -D or -DD. For GNU Make, it's
-d or --debug. Caution, though, dump the output from the command to a file,
because there is a *lot* of it.

You might want to read http://freecode.com/articles/what-is-wrong-with-make, as a piece of on-the-side illumination.

Comment: link is gone, see web archive: [what is wrong with make](https://web.archive.org/web/20161120042049/http://freecode.com/articles/what-is-wrong-with-make)

Answer (score 0):

To parse a Makefile and build a naive dependency list

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parse_makefile(makefile_content):
    # Dictionary to hold the graph, with each key being a target and the value being a set of dependencies.
    dependency_graph = defaultdict(set)

    # Process each line in the Makefile content
    for line in makefile_content.splitlines():
        # Strip leading and trailing whitespaces
        line = line.strip()

        # Skip if it's a recipe line (starts with a tab) or empty/comment line
        if not line or line.startswith('\t') or line.startswith('#'):
            continue

        # Split the line into target and dependencies parts
        if ':' in line:
            parts = line.split(':')
            target = parts[0].strip()
            dependencies = parts[1].split()
            # Add dependencies to the graph
            dependency_graph[target].update(dependencies)

    return dependency_graph

# Example usage:
makefile_content = """
all: prog1 prog2

prog1: prog1.o utils.o

prog2: prog2.o

prog1.o: prog1.c

prog2.o: prog2.c

utils.o: utils.c
"""

dependency_graph = parse_makefile(makefile_content)
for target, dependencies in dependency_graph.items():
    print(f"{target}: {dependencies}")
```

The dependency_graph returned by the function will be a dictionary data structure where each key is a string representing a target in the Makefile, and the associated value is a set of strings representing the dependencies of that target. The sets ensure that each dependency is unique (no duplicates) and allow for efficient membership testing.

Given the example Makefile content provided in the function, the dependency_graph would look like this:

```
{
    'all': {'prog1', 'prog2'},
    'prog1': {'prog1.o', 'utils.o'},
    'prog2': {'prog2.o'},
    'prog1.o': {'prog1.c'},
    'prog2.o': {'prog2.c'},
    'utils.o': {'utils.c'}
}
```

In this graph representation:

The key 'all' has a set containing 'prog1' and 'prog2' because all depends on prog1 and prog2.
The key 'prog1' has a set containing 'prog1.o' and 'utils.o' because prog1 is built from prog1.o and utils.o.
Similarly, other targets have their dependencies listed in sets.
This dictionary represents the dependency graph, illustrating how each target is related to its dependencies. This representation can then be used to perform tasks like determining build order or detecting circular dependencies.